# Report Viewer print more pages that in preview

Tags: report, reportviewer

I created a report using Report Viewer. All works fine with the data and when I click the button to preview the report is like I want.
The problem is when I send the order to printer, she print 4 pages, the first equals the report and the other only with header and footer.

Anyone know what's the problem?

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: I tried delete the header and footer from pages and now the report send 1 page with the information and 3 blank.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have problem with PageSize or probably there are some elements which go beyound the side boundaries on your page.